# JS/CSS Scroll to top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have these simple tabs on my website but I'm missing a feature.

I'm reading a tab and scrolling to the bottom. When I'm done with reading the tab and switching to another tab, the scroll position stays the same.

What I'm trying to achieve is, automatically scroll to the top whenever a tab is clicked. (Not to the top of the whole page, just scroll to the top of the tab content.)

Also, is there a way to display the 'scroll to top' function in a smooth transition / animation?

```js
const btn = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('button'))
btn.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.addEventListener('click',function(){
    btn.forEach((item) => {item.classList.remove('active')})
    item.classList.add('active')
    document.getElementById('tab').setAttribute('data-tab', index)
  })
}  
)


// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

// Get the header
var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the header when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
button {background-color:#000;color:#fff}


.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.tabs {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all .9s ease-in-out; 
    -moz-transition: all .9s ease-in-out; 
    -ms-transition: all .9s ease-in-out; 
    -o-transition: all .9s ease-in-out; 
    transition: all .9s ease-in-out;
    pointer-events:none;
 
}

.tabs> * {
    width: 100%;
}

.tabs[data-tab='1'] {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.tabs[data-tab='2'] {
    transform: translateX(-200%);
}
.tabs[data-tab='3'] {
    transform: translateX(-300%);
}
.tabs[data-tab='4'] {
    transform: translateX(-400%);
}

.inliner {

    white-space: nowrap;
}

.inliner > * {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
    font-size: 1rem;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    vertical-align: top;
    word-spacing: normal;
    white-space: normal;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}



.textabove {
  font-size:40px;
   margin-bottom:40px}
```

```html
<div class="textabove">Some content above the tabs</div>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div id="myHeader"> 
      <button> Tab 1</button>
       <button> Tab 2</button>
       <button> Tab 3</button>
  </div>        
    <div id="tab" class="tabs inliner">
        <div>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
        
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
       
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Content 3</h2>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unnecessarily complex; just use an anchor tag

Comment: @Dexygen Can you explain? Thanks for your reply

Comment: Google is your friend

Comment: At the end of your click handler just add **location.href = "#tab";** that uses your tab parent's ID as the anchor target. Since the pound sign is first, it will go directly there without refreshing the page

Comment: @Dexygen Of course i googled as soon as i saw your answer. But still dont understand a thing. What is unnecessarily complex? The snippet i provided? if so, how? 1 part is from codepen, the other part from w3schools.. didnt know it could be less complex than that. Also, what to do with an anchor tag? Create tabs, but how? What about the existing transitions?

Comment: @imvain2 Many thanks, tried to do so but couldnt really figure out where exactly to put the snippet

Comment: @needhelp00 just add it on a new line below **document.getElementById('tab').setAttribute('data-tab', index)**

Comment: @needhelp00 You can do this by using an anchor link hash which corresponds to an object with that id. More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement/hash. The browser api runs and facilitates this behaviour. The JS and CSS make it more appealing by slowing down the scroll and styling the appearance of the feature. The question is why to do this, the user might get annoyed with the page jumping on every tab click.

Comment: You are going to have to learn to master the anchor tag if you want to get anywhere as a web developer.  It's at they very foundation of HTML.  You can find the basics at thousands of place on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `scroll(x,y)` Function of an `Element`.
[Doc here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll)

Like this:

```
//After the line 6 (OR before) on Js ("document.getElementById('tab').setAttribute('data-tab', index))
window.scroll(0,sticky)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Element.scrollIntoView()` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#syntax))
So for your transition to the top page, you can use `Window.scrollTo({ top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' })`

```js
const btn = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('button'))
btn.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.addEventListener('click',function(){
    btn.forEach((item) => {item.classList.remove('active')})
    item.classList.add('active')
    document.getElementById('tab').setAttribute('data-tab', index)
    // You can use Element.scrollIntoView
    document.getElementById('tab').scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  })
}  
)


// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

// Get the header
var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the header when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
button {background-color:#000;color:#fff}


.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.tabs {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all .9s ease-in-out; 
    -moz-transition: all .9s ease-in-out; 
    -ms-transition: all .9s ease-in-out; 
    -o-transition: all .9s ease-in-out; 
    transition: all .9s ease-in-out;
    pointer-events:none;
 
}

.tabs> * {
    width: 100%;
}

.tabs[data-tab='1'] {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.tabs[data-tab='2'] {
    transform: translateX(-200%);
}
.tabs[data-tab='3'] {
    transform: translateX(-300%);
}
.tabs[data-tab='4'] {
    transform: translateX(-400%);
}

.inliner {

    white-space: nowrap;
}

.inliner > * {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
    font-size: 1rem;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    vertical-align: top;
    word-spacing: normal;
    white-space: normal;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}



.textabove {
  font-size:40px;
   margin-bottom:40px}
```

```html
<div class="textabove">Some content above the tabs</div>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div id="myHeader"> 
      <button> Tab 1</button>
       <button> Tab 2</button>
       <button> Tab 3</button>
  </div>        
    <div id="tab" class="tabs inliner">
        <div>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
        
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
       
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Content 3</h2>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```